# php laravel compact and use attibute not work

Tags: php, laravel

in my controller is compact object with this code

```
public function getEdit($var = '') {
    $words = Word::where('title', $var)->get();

    return view('dict.edit', compact('words'));

}
```

In my view i need to use attibute title form words and then i call.

```
  <h3>{{ $words->title }}</h3>
```

it have error problem say Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$title .

Answer (score 2):

It's because `$words` is a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections).

You should use it inside a loop, for example:

```
foreach($words as $word){
    $word->title;
}
```

If you only want the first object, you may use the `first` method, just as follows:

```
$words->first()->title
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're outputting this in your view, then you can use the Blade syntax for looping through your `Collection`.

```
@foreach ($words as $word)
    {{ $word->title }}
@endforeach
```

And for fun, the `Collection` class has some call methods, so if you wanted to list all titles in one go:

```
$words->implode('title', ', ')
```